# How to make the radio buttons select only one option

Tags: html

I am looking for the code that would allow the radio button option to select only one option.

Below is what I have tried:

Yes

No

```
                            <div class="check">
                                <div class="inside"></div>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li> 
                            <input type="radio" id="{concat('NA', ./Identifier)}" name="{concat('NA', ./Identifier)}" value="{concat(./Identifier/text(), 'NA')}" />
                            <label for="{concat('NA', ./Identifier)}">Not Applicable</label>

                            <div class="check">
                                <div class="inside"></div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
```

Comment: assign same `name` property to both radio inputs.

Comment: If you want that user can select only one radio among multiple radio buttons then you need to use the same name attribute for all.

Answer (score 2):

Make each radio button have the same name:

```
<input type="radio" name="radioButton" value="Yes" />
<input type="radio" name="radioButton" value="No" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make toggle or single select from multiple then you have to give the same name to all radio type every elements.

```html
<input type="radio" name="rb" value="One" />
<input type="radio" name="rb" value="Two" />
<input type="radio" name="rb" value="Three" />
<input type="radio" name="rb" value="Four" />
```